# How to add a second rule to str_replace?

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to replace all spaces with "-" in order for me to create a URL

```
<?php echo strtolower( str_replace(' ', '-', $city['name']) ); ?>
```

How can I add a second rule to that code, so that I can not only replace all spaces... but I want to replace all "+" signs with a "&" sign as well.

Answer (score 5):

`str_replace()` allows you to pass in arrays rather than strings so you can replace multiple characters/terms at once:

```
echo strtolower( str_replace(array(' ', '+'), array('-', '&'), $city['name']) );
```

Docs for `str_replace`: http://php.net/str_replace

Note that you can pass arrays to `str_replace` starting in PHP 4.0.5.